# Should Domain Entities be dependant on factories?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Please see the code below:

```
public IEnumerable<DenominationNumberRequired> CalculateDenominationsFor(int cost) 
    {
        var target = cost;
        foreach (var denomination in currency.AvailableDenominations.OrderByDescending(a => a))
        {
           var numberRequired = target / denomination;
           if (numberRequired > 0)
           {
               yield return new DenominationNumberRequired(denomination, numberRequired);
           }
           target = target - (numberRequired * denomination); 
        }
    }
```

Notice that this domain object is responsible for creating DenominationNumberRequired  object(s) even though it is not a factory.  Should I be injecting a factory into this entity to create the DenominationNumberRequired object(s)? This seems to suggest that I should not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035810/should-domain-objects-have-dependencies-injected-into-them.  However, likewise; a domain object that creates other domain objects does not seem right either due to the single responsibility principle.

Comment: Why don't you just have an orchestrator eg.: an application/domain service that does this job, and only pass in value objects, primitives to your entity methods? So you won't have such coupling.

Comment: @kayess, because I believe that would make the domain model anemic.

Comment: Not at all, since you have these services for 1. orchestrating, 2. place for logic that does not fit an entity/AR. The rest of the behavior is still locked in/pushed down into your entity.

Comment: I don't see the value of a factory here. However I thinkg that the parameter `value` should very likely not computed here, but computed in the Offer constructor passing the valueCalculator (this assume that this interface is really needed, like having multiple implementation for different cases). Factory are not used just to remove the "new" keyword, they're used to abstract more complex construction involving : a complex object, multiple objects related to each other, specific logic that can eventually depends on configuration files, ...

Comment: If I got it right, it looks like you have two entities that *could be* aggregate roots: Member and Offer. What about if Offer is created first in some application service, that this service publishes an event "Offer created", and the other application service assigns it to a member, so that Member is not coupled to Offer object itself, but only to its id? I believe it would look way cleaner.

Comment: What benefits are obtained by using a factory?  What benefits are obtained by injecting that factory into a domain object?

Comment: @Robert Harvey, the benefit of using a factory is that the creation logic is encapsulated in its own class (single responsibility).

Comment: OK.  Does that benefit exceed the cost in this particular instance?  Do you really need the benefit?

Comment: @Robert Harvey, yes it does.  However, I am trying to think longer term when the team size increases from five to nine.  I am trying to take a long term perspective on everything I do at the moment.  It makes everything seem a lot more difficult then it needs to be sometimes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Thanks for clarifying that.  Do you think a factory should be used in my scenario to create DenominationNumberRequired instances?

Comment: The purpose of a factory method is to create objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that will be created.  Is that a capability that you require?

Comment: @Robert Harvey, no.  In this specific case the same class will always be created.

Comment: Then I don't think you need a factory or factory method.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, thanks.  That is what I thought.  The only thing I could think of is that I could mock a factory when testing.  I cannot think of a reason why I would need to mock a factory.  However, that doesn't mean there is no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I be injecting a factory into this entity to create the Offer object?

Short answer: *Probably* not.

The factory can be a good idea without injecting it into the Member entity.

For example, you can pass it in as an argument to the method

```
public IEnumerable<DenominationNumberRequired> CalculateDenominationsFor(int cost, Factory<DenominationNumberRequired> factory) 
    {
        var target = cost;
        foreach (var denomination in currency.AvailableDenominations.OrderByDescending(a => a))
        {
           var numberRequired = target / denomination;
           if (numberRequired > 0)
           {
               yield return factory.create(denomination, numberRequired);
           }
           target = target - (numberRequired * denomination); 
        }
    }
```

This might be an advantage if you want additional flexibility in the *types* of your denominations; in your example, `CalculatedDenominationsFor` doesn't actually care about the type at all, so you might instead write....

```
public IEnumerable<T> CalculateDenominationsFor(int cost, Factory<T> factory)
```

In a case where you actually have constraints on the type (because you need access to methods in the interface), then you might make the signature more specific

```
public IEnumerable<T> CalculateDenominationsFor(int cost, Factory<T> factory) where T : DenominationNumberRequired
```

(Disclaimer: JVM programmer trying to guess at C# spellings).

> Are you saying that the factory instance should be created in the application service and passed to the domain layer?

You could do that - as far as the application is concerned, the factory is just an opaque handle that it is supposed to pass when the time comes.  And yes, in doing that, you end up passing the handle through a lot of locations that don't care very much about it.

That might be a hint that your boundaries aren't in the right places, or that you aren't using the right abstractions as your arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Are you saying that the factory instance should be created in the application service and passed to the domain layer? This would mean I would have to pass from the application service to domain entity 1 and then from domain entity 1 to domain entity 2.