# Should a class not contain constants only?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Please see the code below:

```
public class EnglishCurrency : Currency
{
    private static readonly decimal[] _denominations= 
    {
         0.01M,  0.02M,  0.05M, 
         0.10M,  0.20M,  0.50M,
         1.00M,  2.00M,  5.00M,
        10.00M, 20.00M, 50.00M,
    };

    public override IEnumerable<decimal> GetDenominations() => _denominations;
}
```

Is it a bad idea to have a class that contains constants only like this? The reason I am doing this is so that I can inject a Currency (EnglishCurrency; SpanishCurrency etc) into another class.  However, I wander if there is a better way of approaching it.

Everywhere I am reading suggests that a class should not contain constants only.  Therefore I believe there may be another approach.

Comment: Why the `public override`? In fact, why is it even a method? Just do `public decimal[] Values {get} = { 0.1M, ... };`

Comment: "*Everywhere I am reading suggests that a class should not contain constants only*". Then I'd suggest you are reading in the wrong places. That's the price you pay though for heading down the RDM rabbit hole... :)

Comment: @DavidArno polymorphism

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer, you mean inheritance? Yuck. Why ever would the OP have such a simple class inherit from a base class?

Comment: @DavidArno Presumably there are other kinds of currency.  Really this needs a base class in order for the rest of the code to not depend on this.  That means later when this is swapped out for an implementation based on configuration, for example, nothing else should need to change.

Comment: @JimmyJames, It's C# code. An `ICurrency` interface would suffice. No base class needed.

Comment: @DavidArno Sure that's a probably a better choice but you agree with the larger point, I gather.

Comment: @JimmyJames, definitely. :)

Comment: @David Arnno, I like the idea of an interface a lot.  It would actually make things simpler in this case.  However, a EnglishCurrency is a Currency.  Therefore I am thinking it should be inheritance.  Why should it be an interface?

Comment: @w0051977 inheritance is generally evil

Comment: Have a look at [what happens when a tester gets hands on that code](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

Comment: I personally wouldn't create classes like this. I'd use a dictionary of `Func<IEnumerable<decimal>>` and would `Select` over the array to prevent it being mutated.

Comment: "However, a EnglishCurrency is a Currency. Therefore I am thinking it should be inheritance" I think you are putting too much into the difference between interfaces and base classes.  The is-a relationship also applies to interfaces.

Comment: @David Arno, thanks.  Would this issue not also effect the code you posted here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361359/what-is-the-benefit-of-encapsulating-a-collection-inside-a-class.  Can you post some code in an answer?

Comment: @David Arno, your link above does not work (the link that says:  look at what happens when a tester gets hands on that code.),  Could you post it again? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why it's not working for you, as it works fine for me: https://sharplab.io/#v2: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

Comment: I see a blank window (I have tried two PCs).  Could you post the code in a comment? I was originally able to see it in December.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fine. Here's the thing, your class *does not contain **only** constants!*

It has the method `GetDenominations()`.

I do not see anything wrong with this class at all, keep up the good work :)

Comment: Thanks.  Would this be a value type in the DDD world? Also should it have a .Equals and .Hashcode?

Comment: @w0051977 Why did you edit the question? I liked the first class... this class makes no sense

Comment: I agree.  There is far too much programming/design advice that focuses on how to write code with no context around problem solving.  If your solution works, is easy to understand and can be easily replaced when you need to add to the design, it's fine.  All of these seem to be met by this approach.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer , I was editing my question as you were answering to try and make it clearer.  However, I think you have understood it  as it was so I have changed it back.  Could you answer the question in my first comment? Thanks.

Comment: I would note that the `EnglishSummertime`  example seems to be kind of silly, though.  You could have a single summertime class that takes the months as a parameter.  It still is easy to swap out with a real implementation so not a problem per se.  Sometimes it's valuable to do something like this when you are working on another part of the application and want to defer some work for later.

Comment: @JimmyJames his original question made more sense, fortunately he changed it back,

Comment: @w0051977 yes these are value objects (the values). The term value object does not really apply to the EnglishCurrency class itself, it is also not an entity object...

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer, I am confused by your last comment.  You seem to say it is a value object and then it is not a value object (in the same comment).  Could you revise your comment? Sorry.  Also, should I be implementing .Equals and .Hashcode? There are no variables in the class.

Comment: @w0051977 you are using the "primitive obsession" anti-pattern. If you returned instances of  EnglishCurrency instead of just decimals, it would be a value class. Right now, it is neither a value class nor a entity class, just an infrastructure class.

https://www.google.com/search?q=primitive+obsession

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer, Could you have a look at my other question here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/362379/should-domain-entities-be-dependant-on-factories.  It is fairly similar.